# 13.10 doesn't boot on Vaio Pro 13

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, vaio, grub-efi

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my new Vaio Pro 13, disabled safe mode, but used UEFI and not legacy mode.
I did an encrypted LVM installation and erased the complete SSD.
It booted just fine from USB, but after installation it doesn't boot.
The Vaio failed boot screen appears.

I then tried this advice here: [13.10 on vaio pro with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360285/13-10-on-vaio-pro-with-uefi)
sadly it fails for me with

> "/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow."

I then tried mounted the encrypted partition with Nautilus and tried this: [Cannot update grub with parameters on live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207663/cannot-update-grub-with-paramters-on-live-usb)
With /dev/sda2 and then to install GRUB to /dev/sda.
Didn't succeed and warned me that the

> "GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't
>   be possible"

What do i have to do, go fix GRUB and be able to boot my finished install?
Here's my Boot Repair Log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6386598/

I would really appreciate any help, 
I'm so happy to finally be able to ditch my big fat Macbook Pro and use Ubuntu on my new, light Vaio Pro, if only I could fix GRUB.

best,
x

Comment: some more data: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6382288/ http://paste.ubuntu.com/6382307/

Comment: Your `fdisk` output is useless for the reasons stated in that output: `GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.` Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates to a pastebin site.

Comment: here you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6383513/  thank you for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have it running with efi now.
here's a summary of things to do: http://steffankarger.nl/2013/12/10/ubuntu-13-10-on-the-sony-vaio-pro-13/

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be booting just fine, or at the very least getting to a GRUB boot menu when you boot. The fact that you're not suggests you've got a defective EFI. I therefore recommend that you check your manufacturer's site for an update. (Most manufacturers call their EFIs "BIOSes," although really they aren't.) If that doesn't help, try the following, in sequence, stopping once you get Linux booting:

1. Re-run Boot Repair again.
2. Boot to an emergency system, mount `/dev/sda1` somewhere, create a directory on that partition called `EFI/BOOT`, and copy `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.
3. Try using a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) If it boots up, select either of the `vmlinuz*` options, hit F2 or Insert twice, and add `ro root=/dev/sda3` to the boot options. If this boots Linux, try installing the Debian-package version of rEFInd. In theory, this should get the computer booting using rEFInd, and without a need to use F2/Insert to add kernel options.
4. If rEFInd doesn't come up when you reboot, then boot to Linux via the rEFInd USB/CD-R and type `sudo mvrefind.sh /boot/efi/EFI/refind /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` in a Terminal window.
5. If that doesn't bring rEFInd up, reboot into Linux and type `sudo /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot`.
6. If that doesn't bring rEFInd up, then return the computer to the store for a refund; it's hopelessly defective. One caveat: If you can get to rEFInd but Linux isn't working, it's possible you've got an encryption/LUKS problem. I've never used this technology, so I'm not sure of precisely how it interacts with boot loaders, particularly on EFI systems.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by just using legacy mode.
after i and some people from my local hackerspace spent several hours trying to get EFI to work.

in the end, i don't care if it's EFI or not, if it boots fast.

thanks for all the help!