# Ubuntu 13.10 on Vaio pro 13, does not boot

Tags: boot, grub2, vaio, boot-repair

I have a problem installing Ubuntu 13.10 on a Sony Vaio Pro 13. Here are the steps I followed so far (with no success in booting in 13.10):

1. The Vaio came with Win 8 pre-installed so I created an image.
2. I used an Ubuntu 13.10 (64bit) live USB to try ubuntu and installed it in the system wiping out win 8 in the process.
3. I tried to boot ubuntu with no success, cannot find the operating system error message
   so I
4. Used the image CDs to get win 8 back again.

Second attempt I follow step 2 above, but I try to follow the instructions in http://steffankarger.nl/2013/12/10/ubuntu-13-10-on-the-sony-vaio-pro-13/ with no success.
Trying to update grub gave me an error.

Then I found this: [13.10 doesn't boot on Vaio Pro 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372970/13-10-doesnt-boot-on-vaio-pro-13)
So I followed the advise and ran boot repair. The output can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6949962/

I still cannot boot into ubuntu. Moreover, I cannot seem to get to bios settings (assist key will not work), neither I can run ubuntu via the live usb any more. Using the recovery image CDs doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it running as try ubuntu for 13.10? If it is not, why don't you use 12.04 LTS version?

Comment: At this moment it cannot run a live usb at all.

Comment: if you have no access to USB port, what about a CD/DVD image? I mean it is good to know if it works well with a live version without installing anything.

Comment: No, unfortunately not..

Answer (score 0):

You can fully shut down the laptop by holding down the power button for 5 seconds. Then start it with the assist button. If that does not work, you can hold shift down when you click on reboot in windows. this should take you to a special menu. there you can reboot in bios (select advanced tools). in bios disable secure boot and set the boot mode to legacy (change from UEFI).

The only way I could install ubuntu was with an external optical drive (usb dvd-rom). just let it boot and don't select anything until the install/try menu appears. After this, proceed normally.

Cheers!