# Dual boot Win 8 / Ubuntu loads only Win

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, vaio, boot-repair

My computer is a Sony Vaio Notebook. I used Ubuntu and Win 8 with dualboot but windows somehow managed to remove the menu to choose the OS at startup. I think the BIOS is UEFI. Secure boot was disabled already and Boot Repair somehow fails.

How can I fix this?

Comment: sda is missing GRUB ... "Place GRUB into sda" using: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: With UEFI you do not have grub in the MBR of sda, just in the efi partition which it is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sony, HP, and many laptop vendors are hard-coded to only boot Windows.

There are several work-a-rounds that suggest you move the grub `grubx64.efi` or `shimx64.efi` file on top of the Windows `/EFI/windows/bootmgfw.efi`. However this isn't recommended because Windows Update will restore `bootmgfw.efi` and you'll be back to only Booting windows.

Instead, I suggest renaming the fallback /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and boot hard drive entry or use rEFInd.

**Make sure you backup the entire EFI partition before making changes.**

You have several options available:

**I.** Move and rename the grub files `grubx64.efi` or `shim64.efi` (for secure boot) to this folder/file `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`

1. Rename /efi/boot/bootx64.efi, copy shim or grub into /efi/boot and name it bootx64.efi  Then boot hard drive entry. New versions of Boot-Repair automatically do this with 'Use the standard EFI file' in advanced options. It also backs up current bootx64.efi which is probably just a copy of Windows .efi boot file.

   From live installer mount the efi partition on hard drive:
   Mount efi partition. check which partition is FAT32 with boot flag. Often    sda1 or sda2 but varies.

   ```
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```

   only if not already existing,

   ```
    sudo mkdir /mnt/EFI/Boot
    sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/* /mnt/EFI/Boot
   ```

   If new folder created, the bootx64.efi will not exist, skip this command

   ```
    sudo mv /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.backup
   ```

   Make grub be hard drive boot entry in UEFI. If not existing, may have to update UEFI also with efibootmgr.

   ```
    sudo mv /mnt/EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
   ```

   If need be, add a new UEFI hard drive boot entry:
   See also

   ```
    man efibootmgr
   ```

   If ESP is sda or default drive & partition entries:

   ```
    sudo efibootmgr -c -L "UEFI Hard drive" -l "\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi"
   ```

   If ESP is not sda1, sdX is drive, Y is efi partition, also NVMe drives :

   ```
    sudo efibootmgr -c -g  -w -L "UEFI hard drive" -l '\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi' -d /dev/sdX -p Y
    sudo efibootmgr -c -L "UEFI hard drive" -l "\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi" -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 2
   ```
2. (This is the same as what Boot-Repair used to do in **II.** Not now recommended:
   Rename /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi and copy grub or shim into /efi/Microsoft/Boot and name it bootmgfw.efi  Then boot Windows entry to boot to grub menu. You have to manually add a grub menu entry to boot renamed Windows efi file. Grub2's os-prober entry boots bootmgfw.efi entry which is now just grub, so it will not work.

   Users who manually moved efi files around see post #6.

   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2101840
   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219452
   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221498&p=13012109#post13012109

**II.** If you ran Boot-Repair's fix for "buggy UEFI" with an older copy it's best to undo it. And then make the change above to use bootx64.efi
To undo and to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.

Any rename either manually or with Boot-Repair will need to be redone after a Windows update as it will restore Windows files.

**III.** Edit Windows BCD, one alternative to Boot-Repair's rename to make shim have Windows name.
Some systems work better to register grub/shim from inside Windows - for those that keep resetting Windows as default.

[Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

https://coderwall.com/p/vfyqkg

**IV.** If Description has to be Windows, then change UEFI description. This really only works for those with just Ubuntu, and no Windows install at all.

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"
```

Restore or a new Windows UEFI entry - assumes default sda1  add -p 2 if sda2 (see man efibootmgr -d drive & -p partition options):

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi"
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1
```

**V.** Some install rEFInd which seems to be another workaround and has nice boot icons.

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html

PPA available to make it easy to install in Ubuntu

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html

**VI.** Restore Ubuntu UEFI entry
sdX is drive, Y is efi partition , if sda2 for example

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L ubuntu -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"  -d /dev/sda -p 1
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Ubuntu" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" -d /dev/nvme0nX -p Y
```

**VII.** Change boot order with efibootmgr:

[Change boot order using efibootmgr](http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr)

**VIII.** Uninstall UEFI entry:

[Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/497720#497720)

**IX.** You can use system UEFI/BIOS settings key (often F2, check your manual) to change the boot order or other UEFI settings that then will be in the UEFI boot menu (often F12):

https://askubuntu.com/a/757426/53503

Comment: Yes! Renaming worked for me!

I mounted the efi partition and copied the files ../EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi to ../EFI/Boot/ and to /EFI/Microsoft/Boot and changed the name of the file as follows. In the ../EFI/Boot directory I overwrote the bootx64.efi with the file and in the ../EFI/Microsoft/Boot i overwrote the bootmgfw.efi with the file . That was all I think.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For those stuck on Windows: I managed to do the rename approach describe in option a1 without leaving Windows. I opened a command window as administrator, then ran `mountvol S: /S` to mount the EFI partition as S:. I had odd issues with going up and down folders, but moving a copy of grubx64.efi a folder at a time into /EFI/Boot, then renaming it to bootx64.efi worked.

Comment: I am surprised the English major who renumbered my post did not do that. I had older comments referring to A: & B: as major sections. :)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer above](https://askubuntu.com/a/486789/141935) didn't work for my friend's HP Pavilion, but I found a decent workaround. It seems that HP's firmware always overwrites the `BootOrder` on every boot and sets Windows first, but it still respects `BootNext`. So I wrote a startup script to set `BootNext` on every boot.

1. Run

   ```
   efibootmgr
   ```

   to find the numeric code of `BootCurrent`. In my friend's case this was `0003`.
2. `/etc/systemd/system/boot-linux-next.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Boot Linux next

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   # Replace '3' in the next line with the appropriate code.
   ExecStart=efibootmgr --bootnext 3

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   systemctl enable --now boot-linux-next.service
   ```

This does mean that if you ever boot something else you will have to manually select Linux on boot next time.

Comment: For my HP, what really worked for me was the most simple solution possible. It just took me two weeks to find in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/757426/53503

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer that has the same problem. My solution is to "reboot" windows, rather than shutdown (which is really just a hybernate.)

By rebooting (Which may trigger updates,) the system shuts down and you can select boot from the bios.  You do have to catch it before it reboots.

I rarely use windows so booting this way doesn't bother me at all.  Unless, of course, windows updates.