# Migrating to new SSD, not booting! (GRUB not loaded)

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I got my new SSD today, and used `dd` to burn the Ubuntu 14.04 image onto a USB. Then I swapped the internal HDD with my new SSD. I booted into the USB, and installed Ubuntu to the SSD. I manually partitioned giving 30 GB to the root and 2 GB as swap. Then it got installed.

The only problem is that I can't boot into the new installation. I get this:

[image: Boot]

So I plugged in the usb, and from it's grub, I manually booted into the installation. That is how I am typing this. Now I proceeded into trying to update grub. It runs with a warning:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when 
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Everything is fine, other than the fact that GRUB residing in the SSD is not being loaded during booting. How do I fix this? My laptop is a [Sony VAIO SVF14212SNW](http://www.sony.co.in/product/svf14212sn)

Comment: Sony's only like to boot Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/458413/how-to-fix-dual-booting-windows-8-and-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-sony-vaio

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking, and I need a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer is UEFI you must first create EFI Boot Partition and your SSD shouldn't use MBR anymore but GPT. I had the same problem with my Sony VAIO. Or if you don't use Windows at all, then change UEFI to BIOS. For sure, Sony VAIO's UEFI implementation sucks.

Comment: This works! In my case, I donot have windows anymore and hence I switched to legacy mode. If anyone ever gets into the same problem, boot into live disk, use `gparted` to create MBR based partition table, and reinstall.