# Ubuntu 14.10 dual boot with preinstalled Windows 8

Tags: 14.10, windows-8, uefi, secure-boot, grub-legacy

I wanted to install Ubuntu with my VAIO laptop with preinstalled Windows 8. So I downloaded the ISO image of ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64 and extracted to my USB drive with Universal USB installer. I allocated 50gb from my HDD for Ubuntu by partitioning it as a new volume. Then I turned off Secure Boot in my BIOS and changed the mode from UEFI to LEGACY mode. Then I installed Ubuntu in that 50Gb drive successfully and it said INSTALLATION COMPLETED. PLEASE RESTART.

I restarted my laptop and it said OPERATING SYSTEM NOT FOUND !!! I tried changing Secure Boot, UEFI/LEGACY mode and nothing worked. Only Windows 8 boots up in my laptop. Ubuntu didn't even showed up in my boot menu. What did I do wrong here? IS there any possibility that I will get to use Windows 8 and Ubuntu along side? Please help me

Comment: Every Sony has this issue as they violate UEFI standards and add description to UEFI boot and only description that works is Windows. But UEFI also boots hard drive entry so we make that be grub or shim. http://askubuntu.com/questions/458413/how-to-fix-dual-booting-windows-8-and-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-sony-vaio  or: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you've got two problems....

### Mixed-mode install

You wrote:

> I turned off Secure Boot in my BIOS and changed the mode from UEFI to LEGACY mode

A lot of pages recommend disabling EFI/UEFI mode and enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support, but it's ***BAD ADVICE.*** The problem is that your computer with Windows 8 pre-installed boots Windows in EFI/UEFI mode. Doing as you described means that you probably installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Those two boot modes don't get along very well; switching boot modes requires either changing them in your firmware (as you've done, or maybe via the built-in boot manager, if its user interface supports this) or using a third-party boot manager (AFAIK, my own rEFInd is the only one that supports this) to switch boot modes on the fly. At best, this is awkward. At worst, it's impossible -- some EFIs don't support making such switches manually.

At best, you can fix the damage done by using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) -- but this can work only if you boot it in EFI mode, and even if you boot it in this way, it's not guaranteed to work. It may be just as easy to disable BIOS/CSM/legacy support and re-install Ubuntu.

Note that Ubuntu *should* install fine with Secure Boot enabled. Disabling it is required on a small minority of computers or if you're dual- or triple-booting with an OS that doesn't support Secure Boot. It's probably best to at least try installing with Secure Boot enabled and disable it only if you run into problems. Note that if you get as far as a GRUB menu, Secure Boot is not a problem.

### Sony VAIO flakiness

Some EFIs, including those used by Sony, are broken. They forget their boot order or EFI boot manager entries, and instead boot straight to Windows. There are various workarounds to these problems, which have been covered in other questions here and elsewhere, such as the ones noted by oldfred:

- [How to fix dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sony Vaio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458413/how-to-fix-dual-booting-windows-8-and-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-sony-vaio)
- [Sony VAIO with Insyde H2O EFI bios will not boot into GRUB EFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi)

I haven't thoroughly re-read those questions today, but on skimming them, they appear to both assume that Ubuntu was installed in EFI mode, so you'll need to re-install or fix your BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation before proceeding.

Note, however, the word I used above: ***broken***. Yes, you can work around problems like this. Do you really want to, though? Would you accept a brand-new car that will start only when the temperature is above 70 degrees Fahrenheit? Would you accept a hammer that will be damaged by hammering nails made of metal? It's the same thing with an EFI that can't remember its boot settings. Manufacturers won't pay attention to such problems unless their figurative noses are shoved into the figurative messes, and that can only be done by returning defective devices and letting the manufacturers know of the problem. Thus, if your computer is new enough and if this is part of your problem, I strongly recommend that you return it and buy something that actually works.