# GRUB not showing when dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have just upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04, where 15.10 dual booted with Windows 10. However, now GRUB does not show, and the system goes directly to Windows.
Last time I installed Ubuntu 15.10, I had the same problem, and it was fixed by changing the default boot loader in Windows as done in this thread
[Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help).
That does, however, not work this time.

I have tried boot-repair, it did not change anything either. It produced the following log: http://paste2.org/6vPC2IUL

I also tried the guide given in this thread:
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).
It did not change anything.

I am using a Sony Vaio, which boots using UEFI.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are showing two ESP - efi system partition. While UEFI allows it, few UEFI will work with two ESP. Better to turn off boot flag on sda3, but do not delete until you know all files needed are in sda1. You have a Sony which has boot issues and it looks like you have done several of them. I looks like you have many entires with "Windows" description booting bootx64.efi. Boot-REpair's 'Use standard file' should make that be a copy of shim. But I would still want a Windows entry and use Sony Original boot entry to boot bootx64.efi.  After cleaning up duplicate ESP see what works.

Comment: AFAIK, no EFI has problems with multiple ESPs; however, the Windows installer can become confused by such a configuration, and it's conceivable some other random tool might become confused, too. It's likely that the problem is with the Sony firmware; many Sony machines have very buggy firmware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sony Vaio?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/458413/how-to-fix-dual-booting-windows-8-and-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-sony-vaio)